# How to use a php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to insert form data into Mysql database and print same form data automatically

Tags: php

Please I need help on how to use a php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to insert form data into Mysql database and print same form data automatically.  I am able to use  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  in my form to send data into the MYSQL database, but I will also like the data to be sent to the printer. See my code below

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?> target="_parent">
```

Comment: so you want to print the data after submit form ?

Comment: Can you define 'print', you just want the array printed, or do you need it in a html table, or you want it to show up in the inputs of the form?

Comment: ....or does "printer" really reference a physical printer, such that your data is available on paper?

Comment: Yes I want to print the data after submit in this format

Comment: @ Brainfeeder The print should print out only the record submitted like a reciept   such as:   Class of Room :&nbsp; <?php echo ($_POST['Class_of_room']); ?>.<br />
  Room Number:&nbsp; <?php echo ($_POST['Room_Number']); ?>.<br />
  Reference Number:<?php echo ($_POST['Reference_Number']); ?>.<br />
  Date:  <?php echo ($_POST['Date']); ?>.<br />
  Customer Name:<?php echo ($_POST['Customer_Name']); ?>.<br />
  Description:<?php echo ($_POST['Description']); ?>.<br />
  Amount:<?php echo ($_POST['Amount']); ?>.<br />
  Cashier Name:<?php echo ($_POST['Cashier_Name']); ?>.<br />

Comment: @ Nico Haase. Yes I mean a physical printer. Infact I need the data submitted into the database printed in a POS printer. Please any idea